Python regular expression adorns string with visible delimiters, yields extra delmiter
I am fairly new to Python and pandas.  In my data cleaning, I would like to see the I performed previous cleaning steps correctly on a string column.  In particular, I want to see where the strings begin and end, regardless of whether they have leading/trailing white space.
The following is meant to bookend each string with a pair of single underscores, but it seems to generate two extra unintended underscores at the end, resulting in a total of three trailing underscores:
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['DOG']})
>>> df.A.str.replace(r'(.*)',r'_\1_',regex=True)
0    _DOG___
Name: A, dtype: object

I'm not entirely new to regular expressions, having used them with sed, vim, and Matlab.  What is it about Python's implementation that I'm not understanding?
I am using Python 3.9 for compatibility with other work.

.* matches twice. Add n=1 argument to your replace function.

Try: df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: f'_{x}_')?

Such an insidious detail. I agree with the comments in the cited Q&A that there are infinite number of zero-width occurrences of .*, not only at the start and end, but everywhere in a string. So matching twice doesn't quite make sense.  In the cited Q&A, an explanation is provided in terms of how regex is implemented.  That makes much more sense, but doesn't make it any more desirable, nor consistent with the implementation-independent intent of the metacharacters (of which .* is supposed to match greedily).

@user24714692: Thanks.  I anchored to the start & end of the string instead: df.A.str.replace(r'^(.*)$',r'_\1_',regex=True). I'm trying to avoid apply because I'm hoping that the built-in replacement works faster across the Series rather than a lambda function meant to be applied element-wise.

@user2153235 Your call. But, both are O(N). Pretty much the same time complexity: See here.

OK, thanks for the O(N).  I googled a bit to fill in this vague impression I got about the slowness of apply, and there seems to be a case for avoiding it when prebuilt alternatives are available, e.g., here, here, and here.  This is not to say that they aren't both O(N).
